# Parent, Child, Child of Child in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have three models, **Province**, **City** and **Job**.

**Province** has the following:

```
public function cities() {
    return $this->hasmany('City');
}
```

**City** has the following:

```
public function province() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Province', 'province_id');
}

public function jobs() {
    return $this->hasmany('Job');
}
```

**Job** has the following:

```
public function city() {
    return $this->belongsTo('City', 'city_id');
}
```

I am trying to get the total number of jobs in each province and the following doesn't work. Would appreciate if someone could point out what I am doing wrong?

```
$province->cities->jobs->count()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not really sure here, but `$provice->cities()->jobs()->count()` might work and, if it does, be way better performance-wise.

Comment: @Raphael_ I did try that earlier as well, unfortunately didnt work, gives the following error:    Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::jobs()

Comment: you can use model's ORM. I've answered this question here:
[laravel-returning-children-of-parents-in-same-table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76388243/5641308)

Answer (score 3):

You have ready-to-use solution in `Eloquent`, no need for loading everything and adding up `count` on the collections.

```
// Province
public function jobs()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('Job', 'City');
}
```

then just:

```
$province->jobs()->count();
```

It runs simple `SELECT count(*)` without loading redundant collections.

---

Additionally, if you need to eager load that count on the collection of provinces, then use this:

```
public function jobsCount()
{
    return $this->jobs()->selectRaw('count(*) as aggregate')->groupBy('province_id');
}

public function getJobsCountAttribute()
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists('jobsCount', $this->relations)) $this->load('jobsCount');

    return $this->getRelation('jobsCount')->first()->aggregate;
}
```

With this you can easily get the count for multiple `provinces` at once (with just 2 queries executed):

```
$provinces = Province::with('jobsCount')->get();

foreach ($provinces as $province)
{
  $province->jobsCount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because cities is a `Collection` you have to loop through each of them to get the jobs number and add them up.

Within controller: Like so;

```
$job_count = 0;

$province->cities->each(function ($city) use ($job_count){
    $job_count += $city->jobs->count(); 
});
```

The `$job_count` would be equal to the total number of jobs within each of it cities.

**Please Note: Be sure to eager load your relations data to reduce the amount of queries that are made on your database.**

```
$province = Province::with('cities', 'cities.jobs')...
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I am trying to get the total number of jobs for the province and not the city. Any suggestions?

Comment: Worth nothing that this potentially issues dozens/hundreds of queries to do the count. So be careful with it.

Comment: @Raphael_ Not if he eager loads it. And the `->count()` is a method on the `Eloquent\Collection` and does not issue a query unless you do something like the following: `$city->jobs()->count();`

Comment: @MattBurrow, Not if he eager loads, exactly. Should probably mention that in the answer.

Comment: No need for this, `hasManyThrough` is the way to go.