# Laravel Relations of model to itself

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to utilize a parent/child relation within one table. Each asset belongs to a parent asset, which is another asset in the assets table/asset model.

Each task in the tasks table has an asset_id record and that asset identified by the ID has a parent_asset_id in its record. I am trying to access the name field of the parent of the asset used in a task and I am getting an error. Here is the code involved:

This is the relation in the asset model:

```
public function parent_asset()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('\pmms\Asset', 'parent_asset_id');
   }
```

and the relation in the task model

```
  public function asset()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('\pmms\Asset');
   }
```

Ina blade file I am trying to access the name field in the asset table like this:

```
$task->asset->parent_asset->name
```

but I get the error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\pmms\resources\views\partials\tasklist.blade.php)
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Results of {{dd($asset->parent_asset())}}:

```
  BelongsTo {#657 ▼
  #foreignKey: "parent_asset_id"
  #otherKey: "id"
  #relation: "parent_asset"
  #query: Builder {#663 ▶}
  #parent: Asset {#664 ▼
    #dates: array:1 [▶]
    #fillable: array:19 [▶]
    #connection: null
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:24 [▼
      "id" => 4
      "agency_id" => 1
      "name" => "Bedrock Park"
      "description" => ""
      "serial_number" => ""
      "asset_category_id" => 5
      "activity_center_id" => 1
      "original_cost" => 0.0
      "in_service_date" => "1920-01-01"
      "expected_lifespan" => 0
      "status" => 1
      "notes" => ""
      "created_at" => "2015-09-14 17:59:47"
      "updated_at" => "2016-10-31 20:01:29"
      "square_feet" => 0
      "gps_longitude" => "0.000000"
      "gps_latitude" => "0.000000"
      "parent_asset_id" => 0
      "supervisor_id" => 0
      "model_number" => 0
      "is_location" => 1
      "asset_sub_category_id" => 0
      "asset_group_id" => 2
      "address" => ""
    ]
    #original: array:24 [▶]
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
  }
  #related: Asset {#682 ▶}
}
```

Code of blade template:

```
<div class="whitebox">

        @forelse ($tasks as $task)
            @if($last_multi_asset_id == 0 or $last_multi_asset_id != $task->multi_asset_task_id)

                <?php 
                if ($task->sourceable_type == '\pmms\Work_order') {
                    $notes = $task->sourceable->explanation;
                } else {                    
                    $notes = $task->supervisor_notes;
                }                       
                ?>

                    <div class="outstanding-task-accordion-div @if ($task->status == 1)status-in-process @elseif ($task->status == 2)status-competed @endif">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#taskModal{!! $i !!}">
                            <div class="panel-title-accordion">                     
                                @if($tasklist_type == 'o' && $tasklist_personal != 1) <div class="col-md-2 task-header-staff">{!! $task->assignee->userName() !!} 
                                    @if(!is_null($task->crew_assignment_id)) <span class="crew text-nowrap">(Crew {!! $task->crew_assignment->id !!})</span> @endif</div> @endif
                                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 task-header-date text-nowrap"> {!! $task->do_date->format('n/j/Y') !!}</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 task-header-asset">@if($task->multi_asset_task_id > 0) Multi-Asset Task @else {!! $task->asset->name !!} - {!! $task->asset->parent_asset->name !!} 
                                @endif
                                @if(!is_null($task->crew_assignment_id)) <span class="crew text-nowrap">Crew {!! $task->crew_assignment->id !!}</span> @endif</div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 task-header-task">{!! $task->sourceable->name !!}</div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 task-header-priority-level text-nowrap">Priority: {!! $task->priority_level !!}</div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 task-header-hours text-nowrap">Hours: {!! $task->hours !!}</div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 task-header-status text-nowrap">{!! $task->status_text() !!}</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="clear-both"></div>

                        <!-- Inside of panel -->
                        @if ($task->multi_asset_task_id > 0)
                            @include('partials.tasklist_accordion_multi')
                        @else
                            @include('partials.tasklist_accordion_indi')
                        @endif
                        <!-- End inside of panel -->


                <?php 
                    $i++;
                    $last_multi_asset_id = $task->multi_asset_task_id;
                ?>
            @endif <!-- Ends the multi_asset if  -->
        @empty
            @if (isset($staff))
                There are no {!! $text !!} tasks for {!! $staff['first_name'] !!} {!! $staff['last_name'] !!} {!! $text2 !!}. 
            @else
                There are no tasks.
            @endif
        @endforelse

</div>
```

Comment: Please post result of `{{ dd($task) }}` and code from the template.

Comment: Shouldn't be the relation in the Asset model be: public function asset() {return $this->belongsTo('\pmms\Asset', 'asset_id');}

Comment: There is no 'asset_id' field, just 'id'. I tried using 'id' as you suggest and it doesn't crash, it just grabs the id of the same asset, not that of its parent.

Comment: @Alexy Mezenin - I added the elements you requested.

Comment: If you do $task->asset->parent_asset_id does it give the id of the parent asset?

Comment: Yes, it does, as expected.

Comment: @circle1 you should unfold relations. Also, it's better to `dd($tasks)`. And please explain what is `sourceable`?

Comment: Maybe these can help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/finding-children-of-parents-in-same-table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122849/laravel-returning-children-of-parents-in-same-table

Comment: @Gilko - thank you but those are regarding finding the child records, which is working fine for me. It is the reverse going up the hierarchy to find the parent_asset->name from the child asset that is not working.

Comment: I posted with the relation expanded as requested.
 If I 'dd($tasks)' the result is a collection of 75 tasks and that is impractical to post here.
'sourceable' is a polymorphic relation of the source of a task, which could be a primary_task_type or a work_order or a project. It has no bearing on the problem at hand, which is traversing the relation backwards from the child to the parent object.

Comment: I changed the dd() to be the results of dd($asset->parebt_asset()). It shows the parent asset and all of its data fields in the container "parent". So, I need to figure out - how do I access the name value of that parent asset?

Comment: you can use model's ORM. I've answered this question here: [laravel-returning-children-of-parents-in-same-table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76388243/5641308)