# Laravel 5.5 return parents of children in same table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Is there a proper way to fetch all parent categories of a child category in Laravel?

**categories table:**

```
id  | level | name   | parent_id
--- | ------| -------|----------
1   |  1    | Cat0   | -1
2   |  2    | Cat01  | 1
3   |  3    | Cat02  | 2
4   |  2    | Cat01a | 2
```

**Category model:**

```
class Category extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [

        'id', 'level', 'name', 'parent_id'
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function items()
    {

        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

It seems pretty difficult to get a collection with all parents from `id = 4`.

I have tried to change my Model like this:
[Laravel returning children of parents in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122849/laravel-returning-children-of-parents-in-same-table)

..but it does not show the desired result.

**My Controller class:**

```
class FrontEndController extends Controller
{

    public function item($item_slug, $id = null) {

        $item = Item::where('item_slug', '=', $item_slug)
            ->orWhere('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();

        $categories = $item->category()->first();
        $categoryTree = [];

        array_push($categoryTree, $categories);

        for($l = $categoryTree[0]['level']; $l > 1; $l--) {

            if((int)$l === $categoryTree[0]['level']) {

                $c = Category::where('id', '=', $categoryTree[0]['parent_id'])->first()->toArray();

            } else {

                $c = Category::where('id', '=', end($categoryTree)['parent_id'])->first()->toArray();
            }

            array_push($categoryTree, $c);
        }


        return view('public.item')->with([
            'item' => $item,
            'attributes' => $item->attributes()->get(),
            'categories' => array_reverse($categoryTree),
        ]);
    }
}
```

This obviously works, I get all categories and subcategories in an array but not together as a clean collection.

Comment: Show us your view shear code !!

Comment: You should set `parent_id` to NULL if you want to work the same way as the answer you posted. In the migration file, use `nullable()` to do this.

Comment: adjacent list are not great if you need a tree structure as you will end up in recursion to handle this, look into nested sets or closure tables.

Comment: @lagbox my old friend! :)  adjacent list is perfectly fine, just like nested sets and closure tables. It all depends on the use case, dataset size and level of nesting. happy coding!

Comment: you can use model's ORM. I've answered this question here: [laravel-returning-children-of-parents-in-same-table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76388243/5641308)